# Icon (.ico) to XAML Path Geometry?

Tags: xaml, icons, ico

I have an existing Windows icon (.ico) file, that I would like to use in a WPF application.  Are there any good tools for converting an .ico icon to an XAML Path Geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML Paths are a vector format and ICOs are bitmaps, so a simple conversion isn't possible.

You could try to open the ICO in a vector software like Inkscape, outline it with Paths then export it as XAML.

If the path is not a requirement, you can also use the .ico in the WPF application directly: simply set it as an Image's Source.

```
<Image Source="test.ico"/>
```